# LuaLaTeX and multilanguage support

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

I've a little issue managing fixed names in my TeX class. I'm using the `babel` package for multilanguage hyphenation support so far, but I would like to deactivate the fixed names provided by `babel`.

I know it's possible to renew all fixed strings/names via:

```
\addto\captions<LANG>{
  \renewcommand{...}
    {...}
}
```

but to be honest, I would appreciate to do it just by `\newcommand{}{}` my own. So that there is no link between the choosen hyphanation language and my used fixed names or any other dependency.

Is there any option to turn off the fixed names of `babel` (`\RequirePackage[englisch.hyphen]{babel}` not working)? Or is there any alternative way to get multilanguage hyphenation in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you switch between languages, the `\captionsLANG` mechanism is what allows automatically changing the fixed words. Can you be more specific about your aim?

Comment: @greg: well, I just don't want the fixed names on a per-language basis nor in any dependency to a package. just a clean \newcommand{\var}{string}... =)

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
\renewcommand{\captionsenglish}{}
```

and the same for all languages you load, then the commands will do nothing and in particular the fixed words won't change with language.

However, `babel` provides the `otherlanguage*` environment that *doesn't* apply `\captions<LANG>` and just switches to the hyphenation and language features of the selected language.

There is also the `hyphenrules` environment that just enables hyphenation rules for the selected language.

Here's an example; note that the French colon is used in the second and third lines, while it's not used in the fourth line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Here's the table of contents name: \contentsname

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
En français la table des matèries est nommée: \contentsname
\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{french}
En français la table des matèries est nommée: \contentsname
\end{otherlanguage*}

\begin{hyphenrules}{french}
En français la table des matèries est nommée: \contentsname
\end{hyphenrules}

\end{document}
```

[image]